# How serial resistors actually reduce EMI?

Tags: resistors, serial, noise, emc, theory

I am recently working with a GSM based system, and there was this advice in the datasheet of the GSM module:

> 22 Ω resistors should be connected in series between the module and
>   the SIM card so as to suppress the EMI spurious transmission and
>   enhance the ESD protection.

I tried to do a little search and I have found a document, [PCB Design Guidelines
For Reduced EMI](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/szza009/szza009.pdf), it has similar statement in it, but no explanation.

> Put a 50 –100 Ω resistor in series with every output pin, and 35 –50 Ω
>   resistor on every input pin.

An other part says:

> **(Series Termination, Transmission Lines)**
>
> Series resistance is an inexpensive solution to termination and
>   ringing problems, and is the preferred method for microcomputer-based
>   systems where minimizing the differential-mode noise is also a
>   concern.

One more possibly related part:

> **Impedance Matching at Inputs**
>   and again, the series resistance is the most likely solution. Resistance placed at the driver increases
>   the output impedance, as seen by the trace and the input pin, thus
>   matching the high impedance of the input

I have found something in this document as well, [Understanding Radiated EMI](https://www.silabs.com/Marcom%20Documents/Resources/EMI-guide.pdf) it says:

> Add series resistance?  May help
>    - Less current (good and bad current) flows through high impedance
>    - May reduce EMI by reducing currents flowing outside IC

All in all, I need a little clarification about the topic, so my question is:

**How serial resistors actually reduce EMI and what is the principle?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well one it slows down the rise time of your signal which reduces the high frequency content.  So that could help you if you didn't need your edges to be that fast.

It also lowers the current flowing through the trace and back through its return path which would lower the strength of the field created around it (and radiated out).

I would add that I've often seen this added lazily, or perhaps by the "emi group" after the design is done.  It's fine if you didn't need the edge rates but if you're trying to go fast slowing down your edges or destroying your [eye](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_pattern) may not be what you want.

Comment: Can you clarify "destroying your eye"?  Also what is the mechanism that slows down the clock edges? Is it some RC time constant?

Comment: For the eye, I think [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_pattern) is what @Some Hardware Guy means.

Comment: I have already added these resitors to the specific lines (the SIM works fine so far), but I was curious about the mechanism. By the way, the specific resistor value is a golden mean? Limit as much the current as we could but on the other hand, do not slow down the rise time too much?

Comment: No if were just talking emi there's no golden value only what works best for your system.  From a purely emi standpoint the largest resistor that let's your system still work reliably would be what you want.  There are other reasons to use series terminating resistors such as ringing, reflection termination, and matching driver output impedance to trace impedance.  I think those topics are covered well elsewhere in the site though.

Comment: @BattleHamster, RE: eye patterns, see [this old question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/73145/what-separates-a-good-eye-diagram-from-a-bad-one).

Comment: @Some Hardware Guy, sorry I have meant the "golden value" for  the 22Ω at this particular module, not for every case, of course. I just wondered, where this specific value (22) comes from, and though that it is the golden mean in this case.

Comment: @Some Hardware Guy, thanks for the answer. I will wait 24 hours before accepting your answer, maybe there will be some more interesting thoughts.

Comment: The lazy person's approach to controlled impedance is to assume all transmission lines are 50 ohms. 22 ohms is "half" of that. http://www.basebandhub.com/pdfs/series_emissions.pdf

Comment: @pjc50, unfortunately the link you provided is now unavailable. May you know an other site with this document?